# resolver problemas con math

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema el cual no logro aclarar como resolver, es sobre Math, en el siguiente problema me da como resultado 12, pero no se porque me da ese  resultado. Saco la raiz cuadrada de los argumentos a y b que son 3 para ambos luego los sumo y saco la potencia del resultado de la suma, pero al hacerlo manualmente, nunca me sale 12, el Math.round redondea al entero mas cercano, pero no se si es desde que saco la raiz de a y b que la raiz es 1.7 pero redondeada me da 2 luego los sumo y saco la potencia o como es ya que lo intente pero nunca me da el resultado de 12.

```
  function abTest(a, b) {
  if(a < 0 || b < 0){
    return
  }

                                      
  return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2))
}

const resultado = abTest(3, 3);
console.log(resultado)// 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo es (2 * sqrt(3))^2 que es igual a (2^2) * (sqrt(3)^2) = 4 * 3 = 12.
(Estás calculando el cuadrado de la raíz cuadrada de un número, que te da de resultado el mismo número)
Si lo que querés es que primero redondee las raíces, debería calcular `Math.pow(Math.round(Math.sqrt(a)) + Math.round(Math.sqrt(b)), 2)`. De esta forma, quedaría
( round(sqrt(3)) + round(sqrt(3)) )^2 que, si no me equivoco, sería (2 + 2)^2
Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos!